# How to output text to file?

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my current code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT id, title FROM titles WHERE type = 'movie' ORDER BY id ASC";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf ("%s-%s\n", $row["id"], $row["title"]);
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

Using `printf` is correctly printing all the rows from my MySQL table.

However, instead of printing it, I want to write it to a text file. Is this possible to do with `printf` or should I be doing something else?

Comment: Use File_put_contents

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: You could use a combination of `fopen()` and `fwrite()`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php with append or you could do it from the mysql interface if you have access https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

Comment: You want your output in a separate file? Easy: CTRL+C & CTRL+V

Answer (score 2):

if you want to write it to the disk, on the server, you should look into `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()`

also you could use `file_put_contents`, but that would require you to prepare all the content before writing it to the file (which could lead to high memory usage if you have lots of records) or if you go with the "append" mode, writing 1 line at a time, you'll have all the overhead of opening and closing the file each time

if you want to make the browser download it, instead of just showing the content, then you need to add a header  to the response

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
```

preferably adding some content type before it. for example, in your case:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

Answer (score 1):

fprintf used to write to the file `file_put_contents` also works

```
  $fp = fopen('output.txt', 'w');
  $in = 'text';
  fprintf($fp, '%s', $in);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fprintf()`. It works just like `printf()`, but prints to a file stream.

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    if ($fp = fopen("filename.txt", "w")) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            fprintf ($fp, "%s-%s\n", $row["id"], $row["title"]);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```